# Prove that if $f \in C^r(T)$, then $\hat{f}(n) = o(\frac{1}{|n|^r} )$ as $n \rightarrow ±∞$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

I searched through everything that came up when I searched this question, but didn't come with anything. I'm used to typing in latex, so please excuse any formatting errors.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\widehat f(n)&=\int_{\mathbb{T}}f(x)\,e^{-inx}\,dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{T}}f\Bigl(x+\frac{\pi}{n}\Bigr)\,e^{-in\bigl(x+\tfrac{\pi}{n}\bigr)}\,dx\\
&=-\int_{\mathbb{T}}f\Bigl(x+\frac{\pi}{n}\Bigr)\,e^{-inx}\,dx.
\end{align}$$
Averaging the two expressions for $\widehat f(n)$ we get
$$
|\widehat f(n)|\le\frac12\int_{\mathbb{T}}\Bigl|f(x)-f\Bigl(x+\frac{\pi}{n}\Bigr)\Bigr|\,dx\le\frac{C\,\pi^r}{2\,n^r}\,2\,\pi.
$$